# php if{} elseif{} else{} syntax error

Tags: php

pls help me with code i dont get where is the error

```
$userrole = $row['type'];

if ($userrole = "admin") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../index.php"); 
} elseif ($userrole = "encoder") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mencode.php"); 
} elseif ($userrole = "verifier") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mverify.php"); 
} else ($userrole = "approver") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mapproved.php"); }
```

thnx in advance

Comment: `else` doesn’t take a condition. Also, single `=` is assignment; if you want to compare two values for equality, use `==` or `===`.

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: Also learn switch cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace in your code

```
   $userrole = $row['type'];

if ($userrole == "admin") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../index.php"); 
} elseif ($userrole == "encoder") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mencode.php"); 
} elseif ($userrole == "verifier") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mverify.php"); 
} elseif ($userrole == "approver") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mapproved.php"); }
```

Comment: thnx i use == for the if statement

Comment: anser help so you can click (up arrow) in anser left side and after click right mark

Answer (score 0):

You made the fundamental error of all new PHP developers:

- `if($a=$b)` is an **assignment** statement. It sets `$b` to whatever is on the right.
- `if($a==$b)` is a comparison statement. It compares two values without changing anything.

Change your statements to `($userrole=='…')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$userrole = $row['type'];

if ($userrole == "admin") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../index.php"); 

} elseif ($userrole == "encoder") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mencode.php"); 

} elseif ($userrole == "verifier") {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mverify.php"); 

} else {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: ../mapproved.php"); }
```

Your if statements have to be comparison operators `==` and not assignment operators `=`.

Also `else`is a catch all, so you don't provide it with comparison values like you would with if or else if. I am a c++ programmer, but I've done a little PHP.